# How to get discarded builds and the date of build execution from Jenkins API?

Tags: api, jenkins, build

I'd like to retrieve from Jenkins api information about all builds of specified job.

I've set in configuration to `Discard old builds`:

```
Days to keep builds - 20
Max # of builds to keep - 10
```

1) Is it possible to get information about builds whatare discarded?

Also I could get following information about each not discarded build:

```
"builds" : [
{
  "_class" : "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
  "number" : 34,
  "url" : "http://myUrl/view/Myjob/34/"
}
]
```

I use following url for this: `http://MyUrl/view/MyJob/api/json?tree=builds[url,number]&pretty=true`

2) Is it possible to get date of build execution?

Answer (score 0):

To discard a build means, well, to discard it, i.e. its information is gone.

I can imagine a solution where you:

- collect, store and update(=extend) information about all existing builds on a regular basis
- at times you'd like to know which builds have been discarded:

  - collect the information of all existing builds at this very moment
  - don't update your store, but ...
  - create a diff between the current (C) and the information previously stored in your store (S). The builds that are in S but not in C are the discarded builds.